# Não consigo fazer upload de uma resposta

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Estou a tentar submeter uma resposta a uma pergunta, mas não consigo.
Depois de carregar no botão "Publique sua resposta", fica à espera para sempre e não faz nada.

O Gestor de Tarefas do Windows diz que não estou a enviar nada (tráfego de Internet).
Já tentei submeter com Firefox, Internet Explorer e Chrome. Nenhum funcionou.

No entanto, na consola de erros tenho isto que parece promissor:

```
Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
```

Sendo que aparece referência a "post-validation.pt-BR.js?v=dd011443a789" na mensagem de erro.

Mais alguém tem este problema? Alguém o conseguiu evitar?

Comment: Parece que tem algo no seu que está entalando no validador do site. Consegue postar o conteúdo em algum outro lugar (incluindo título e tags) para podermos ver?

Comment: @bfavaretto Título e tags não tem (é resposta). O conteúdo posso: https://gist.github.com/luiscubal/9013217

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já descobri o problema.
Tinha caracteres Unicode inválidos (como parte precisamente de uma demonstração de caracteres inválidos).
Substituindo por �, o que o github gist fez, ficou o problema resolvido.

Mas para a próxima, uma mensagem de erro a dizer o porquê ajudaria a descobrir o problema.

Obrigado na mesma.

Comment: Ah, por isso que eu fiz um teste de postagem aqui no meta e funcionou. Ele deixou passar o que o github substituiu. Eu estava mesmo desconfiado desses caracteres.